# UIbutton which displays a popover label briefly where the label would show halfway outside the button

Tags: ios, uibutton

How do I create a uibutton, which will show a uilabel of some text briefly something like a speech bubble that will appear and then disappear. The problem is the speech bubble will be a view lying halfway outside the button frame.

thanks for help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a UIButton in the .xib file and give some name.

Add the folowing method in your code.
`- (IBAction)bubbleButn:(UIButton *)btn`

Then right click on the button and see the "Touch Up Inside" part in the menu. Then you can click and drag the right most circle to the files owner in the "Placeholders" section of the Xocde. Then you can see the method name comes in a menu. You can select our method from there.

Next we are going to implement our code.

At first you must declare a UILabel in the .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel *bubbleLabel_;
}

@end
```

and then in the .m file implement the button action and label settings.

```
- (IBAction)bubbleButn:(UIButton *)btn {
    float half = btn.frame.size.width/2;
    float yVal = btn.frame.size.height/2;
    if(bubbleLabel_) {
    /* 
     If you are using 'arc' no need of this statement
     add this in the dealloc method also.
     */
    [bubbleLabel_ release];
    bubbleLabel_ = nil;
}
    bubbleLabel_ = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btn.frame.origin.x+half, btn.frame.origin.y+yVal, 40, 50)];                        
    bubbleLabel_.text = @"Hi";

    [self.view addSubview:bubbleLabel_];

    [self performSelector:@selector(hideBubble) withObject:self afterDelay:3];

}


- (void) hideBubble {
    [bubbleLabel_ removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The label named "Hi" will be there for 3 seconds.

Go on...

Comment: thanks for this, however, i need the bubble to be halfway outside the button too.. like a speech bubble on the button...

Comment: You can modify the frame settings for the UILabel and adjust the frame out side the button.